# Django-allauth initially creates a user- why?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have just added django-allauth to our project.  On launching the app I run no seeding, yet when i check the users there is a single user created: "AnonymousUser".

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
User.objects.all()[0].__dict__

{
    '_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fc0cb644c50>, 
    'id': 1, 
    'password': '!ckXY3T...wUhuko52q',
    'last_login': None,
    'is_superuser': False,
    'username': 'AnonymousUser',
    'first_name': '',
    'last_name': '',
    'email': '',
    'is_staff': False,
    'is_active': True,
    'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 2, 8, 22, 32, 317584, tzinfo=<UTC>)
}
```

When using the django standard auth model no user was created by default.

My settings and custom user model are below:

```
# settings.py

# Authentication
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = True
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE = True


# accounts.models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I can't find any documentation about this in the allauth docs, or by googling variations of "allauth AnonymousUser created".

Why was a user created using allauth, and how can i disable this?

Comment: I don't think this is due to django-allauth. Are you using (django-guardian) [https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian] in your project? This kind of user is created by this package.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar yes- thanks for the lead, I'll look further into this, if you want to write that up as an answer the points are yours

Comment: Very welcome. I am glad I was able to help :)